# 500 Internal Server Error for some but not others

Tags: python, django

My site, https://hendrixia.com, gives an 500 Internal Server error for some users but not others. I have someone helping me debug, but without fruition. He is getting 500 internal server errors on his personal computer and at one of his webservers. I am able to load the site fine. We have no clue what is wrong. Obviously I'm not going to turn debugging on on a live site. But we are running out of options. Can anyone help?

Site is built with python/django. postgresql db. hosted at heroku

Things we've confirmed:

- Ipv6 requests are handled correctly
- https redirect and www redirect are fine

Things that may be suspect:

- I recently removed django-machina from the project entirely. Along (removed) with it went haystack, ckeditor, and other required packages

Comment: Have you tried reloading without cache? That may fix the fact that you don't get an HTTP error code.

Comment: Now I have. Still works for me

Comment: hmm, I'm not sure I can help you, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Non-logged in users got the error but logged in users didn't.